# Joins in R while also spreading out information from one data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am attempting to join together two data frames. One contains records of when certain events happened. The other contains daily information on values that occurred for a given organization.

My current challenge is how to join together the information in the "when certain events happened" data frame fully into the records data frame. Most of dplyr's joins appear to simply join one line together. I need to fully spread out the record information based on start and end dates.

In other words, I need to spread out information from one line into many lines, while simultaneously joining to the daily data table. It is important that I do this in R because the alternative is quite a bit of filtering and dragging in Excel (the information covers thousands of rows).

Below is a representation of the daily data table

```
value   year month  day org link
12        1    1     1  AA  AA-1-1
45        1    1     2  AA  AA-1-2
31        1    1     3  AA  AA-1-3
10        1    1     4  AA  AA-1-4
```

Below is a representation of the records table

```
year month  day org link       end_link       event event_info
 1    1      2  AA  AA-1-1-2    AA-1-1-3         Buy        Yes
 1    2      7  BB  BB-1-2-7    BB-1-2-10        Sell       Yes
```

And finally, here is what I am aiming for in the end:

```
 value  month   day org link      event   event_info
 12      1       1  AA  AA-1-1-1        
 45      1       2  AA  AA-1-1-2    Buy     Yes
 31      1       3  AA  AA-1-1-3    Buy     Yes
 10      1       4  AA  AA-1-1-4
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in R? I have tried using dplyr joins but usually am only able to join together the initial link.

Edit: The second "end" link refers to an end date. In the records table this is all in one line, while the second data frame has daily information.

Edit: Below I have put together a cleaner look at my real data. The first image is of DAILY DATA while the second is of RECORDS OF EVENTS. The third is what I would like to see (ideally).

[Daily data, which will have multiple orgs present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoWII.png)

[Records data, note org id AA and the audience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w9pu.png)

[Ideal combined data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u5Gg.png)

Comment: Seems like you just need to `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather` the second data frame before joining.

Comment: Would that still work if the end link (end date) takes place greater than 2 days out? E.x. in this example there is a 2 day event but some events cover 7 days or 30 days. In other words, will it still "fill" in the event and event_info data in the final frame? Thank you for the help.

Comment: it's not clear what `link` means, only the last number is changing over a timespan ?

Comment: The link is a combination of month, day, and the organization. In the original data set it also includes the year. So there is a "start date link" and an "end date link" in the records of what happened, and, ideally, I could connect this to the beginning and end of the daily records table, and fill in the information between with the event and event info. For example, a start link might reference October 4, and the end link might reference October 17, indicating that for the org something happened during that time.

Comment: you should include the year in your example so we can extract the date and use date operations

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Let me know if these edits help.

Comment: year 1 is 2001 ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper It could be any year, I put 1 for simplicity. If you need to illustrate date operations, use 2001 = 1. The key is I need to link by date, brand, and event types and then bring all the extra info along.

Comment: it's jut that 29 feb is not every year, though it's not in your example, but fair enough, that'll be enough to find a solution :)

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. It should not be a problem for my actual data.

Answer (score 0):

We have first to build some dates in order to build date sequences that we'll `unnest` to get a long version of `df2`, which we right join on `df1`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>%
  separate(link,c("org1","year1","month1","day1")) %>%
  separate(end_link,c("org2","year2","month2","day2")) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  transmute(org,event,event_info, date = list(
    as.Date(paste0(year1,"-",month1,"-",day1)):as.Date(paste0(year2,"-",month2,"-",day2)))) %>%
  unnest %>%
  right_join(df1 %>% mutate(date=as.numeric(as.Date(paste0(year,"-",month,"-",day))))) %>%
  select(value, month, day, org, link, event,event_info)

# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   value month   day   org   link event event_info
#   <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>
# 1    12     1     1    AA AA-1-1  <NA>       <NA>
# 2    45     1     2    AA AA-1-2   Buy        Yes
# 3    31     1     3    AA AA-1-3   Buy        Yes
# 4    10     1     4    AA AA-1-4  <NA>       <NA>
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="value   year month  day org link
12        1    1     1  AA  AA-1-1
                  45        1    1     2  AA  AA-1-2
                  31        1    1     3  AA  AA-1-3
                  10        1    1     4  AA  AA-1-4",h=T,strin=F)
df2 <- read.table(text="year month  day org link       end_link       event event_info
 1    1      2  AA  AA-1-1-2    AA-1-1-3         Buy        Yes
                  1    2      7  BB  BB-1-2-7    BB-1-2-10        Sell       Yes",h=T,strin=F)
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this breaks apart the link function and constructs a date. Would it be simpler to delete the link function and simply rely on columns for Year, Month, Day, and organization? I keep getting a "no applicable method for right_join applied to class 'function" error. I wonder if it would be easier to just have both data frames contain the columns to construct a date and go from there?

Comment: Do you have this error with the precise input data from my post ? I just retested it and it works fine on my side. you're right that I could simplify, I just need my complex formula to parse `end_link`

Comment: It works great with the input data but not when I scaled it up to my full data which contains information across multiple months.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'll need a minimal example that reproduces your issue to help you further.

Comment: I have edited my original post with photos of the dilemma. Let me know if this helps or if more detail is necessary. There are two audience types, potentially, and each orgid might have both.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Data table package, it is for me the best R package to do data analysis. Hope to have properly understood the problem, let me know if it does not work.

The first part creates the data-set (I created the two data.table objects in two different ways just to show both alternatives, you could read your data directly from excel, .txt, .csv or similar, let me know if you want to know how to do this).

```
library(data.table)
value<-c(12,45,31,10)
year<-c(1,1,1,1)
month<-c(1,1,1,1)
day<-c(1,2,3,4)
org<-c("AA","AA","AA","AA")
link<-c("AA-1-1","AA-1-2","AA-1-3","AA-1-4")

Daily_dt<-data.table(value, year,month,day,org,link)

Records_dt<-data.table(year=c(1,1),month=c(1,1),day=c(2,3),org=c("AA","BB"),link=c("AA-1-1-2","BB-1-2-7"),end_link=c("AA-1-1-3","BB-1-2-10"),
                       event=c("Buy","Buy"),event_info=c("Yes","Yes"))

Daily_dt[,Date:=as.Date(paste(year,"-",month,"-",day,sep=""))]
```

To achieve what you want you  need these lines

```
Records_dt=rbind(Records_dt[,c("org","link","event","event_info")],
                 Records_dt[,list(org,link=end_link,event,event_info)])

Record_Dates<-as.data.table(tstrsplit(Records_dt$link,"-")[-1])
Record_Dates[,Dates:=as.Date(paste(V1,"-",V2,"-",V3,sep=""))]
Records_dt[,Date:=Record_Dates$Dates]

setkey(Records_dt,Date)
setkey(Daily_dt,Date)

Records_dt<-Records_dt[,c("Date","event","event_info")][Daily_dt,]
Records_dt<-Records_dt[,c("value","month","day","org","link","event","event_info")]
```

and this is the result

```
> Records_dt
   value month day org   link event event_info
1:    12     1   1  AA AA-1-1    NA         NA
2:    45     1   2  AA AA-1-2   Buy        Yes
3:    31     1   3  AA AA-1-3   Buy        Yes
4:    10     1   4  AA AA-1-4    NA         NA
```

If your input data had more than one event in the same day (with or without the same *org*) something like:

```
> Records_dt
   year month day org     link  end_link event event_info
1:    1     1   2  AA AA-1-1-2  AA-1-1-3   Buy        Yes
2:    1     1   3  BB BB-1-2-7 BB-1-2-10   Buy        Yes
3:    1     1   2  AA AA-1-1-2  AA-1-1-3   Buy        Yes
4:    1     1   3  AA AA-1-2-7 AA-1-2-10   Buy        Yes
```

some tweaks may be required, but am not sure if you required this, so did not add it.

Comment: `day=c(2,7)`, not `c(2,3)`, so your solution fails.

Comment: Thanks, i had missed the part of the relevance of the end dates, thus had misunderstood the problem. I just corrected the code.

Comment: @JuanOssa I received an error at the second to last line of your solution (the first line after Setkey(Daily_dt). The error is below:  Join results in 894 rows; more than 466 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice. NOTE: This error is on my full data set.

Comment: @JuanOssa I have updated my original post with some photos of the data to help clarify some of the issues. I removed the link since a lot of the solution centers around breaking it down anyway into a date.

Comment: I may need to have a better idea of your full data, as this is precisely what I warned at the end of my message. There seem to be duplicates in the records table which need some tweaks. If you check both lines in yellow in the record table, both finish at the same date, thus the code is struggling to include them in the daily table. What do you want the code to do when facing more than one line with the same date? Also, are you only interested in the records whose Orgid= AA? Should the rest be ignored? I ask this because records with the same date and different Orgid may also generate error.